# ntlk: how to get inflections of words

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

I have a list of words, nearly 5000 English words, and for each word I need these inflectional forms:

noun: singular and plural

verb: infinitive, present simple, present simple 3rd person, past simple, present participle (ing form), past participle

adjective: comparative and superlative

adverb

How can I extract these information from a given word (e.g. help) in ntlk via python? (or maybe there is a ready made list)

Comment: There are some downloadable dictionaries as well, which provide such information. You need to find some way to extract the information needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For singularity and plurality you can always use '[pattern-en](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en)' library.